# Serve different Markup Files for Page in Wicket

Tags: wicket, wicket-6

Lets say i want 3 different `*.html` for a `WebPage`. F.e. `page_small.html`,`page_tablet.html`, `page_desktop.html`.
How can i detext the `screensize` and depending on the screen serve one of my 3 `*.html`

I found wickets `getVariation` but i cant find a good explanation or example. But is this the right way and can someone provide an example?

```
@Override
public String getVariation() {
    WebClientInfo info = (WebClientInfo) Session.get().getClientInfo();
    ClientProperties p = info.getProperties();
    p.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    p.setNavigatorJavaEnabled(true);
    System.out.println(p.toString());
    // Defaults to -1 ????
    int width = p.getScreenWidth();


    String size;
    System.out.println("width = "+width);
    if (width < 1024) {
        size = "small";
    } else if (width < 1280) {
        size = "medium";
    } else {
        size = "large";
    }
    String s = super.getVariation();
    return s == null ? size : s + "_" + size;

}
```

but `width= -1`

Answer (score 3):

You need to render at least one page to be able to get the browser info and then use it while rendering the following pages to decide what variation to use.

You can use `getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);` as @svenmeier suggested or use `AjaxClientInfoBehavior` as shown at http://examples7x.wicket.apache.org/ajaxhellobrowser/

But I'd recommend if you use responsive design, i.e. CSS media queries.

Comment: I agree, the CSS solution is the better option!

Answer (score 2):

Your application does not configure Wicket to gather extended browser information:

```
protected void init() {
  getRequestCycleSettings().setGatherExtendedBrowserInfo(true);
}
```